# Elasticsearch email analyzer with uax_url_email tokenizer splits email at @

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an email analyzer in Elasticsearch 1.7, which I expect to handle emails as a whole string and not split them in any way. What happens however is that the email input gets split at the @ character.

this is my template

```
{
  "template": "someindex*",
  "settings": {
    "index.analysis.filter.length-filter.min": "8",
    "index.analysis.analyzer.default.stopwords": "_none_",
    "index.analysis.filter.length-filter.type": "length",
    "index.analysis.filter.length-filter.max": "4999",
    "index.mapper.dynamic": "true",
    "index.analysis.analyzer.default.type": "standard",
    "index.analysis.analyzer.email-analyzer.filter" : ["lowercase","unique"],
    "index.analysis.analyzer.email-analyzer.type" : "custom",
    "index.analysis.tokenizer.email-tokenizer.type" : "uax_url_email",
    "index.analysis.analyzer.email-analyzer.tokenizer" : "email-tokenizer"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "index_analyzer" : "email-analyzer",
          "search_analyzer" : "email-analyzer",
          "type" : "string",
          "fields" : {
            "raw" : {
              "index" : "not_analyzed",
              "ignore_above" : 256,
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true,
        "omit_norms": true
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {
    "someindex": {}
  }
}
```

when I execute this

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/someindex/_analyze?analyzer=email-analyzer' -d 'test.me@gmail.com'
{"tokens":[{"token":"test.me","start_offset":0,"end_offset":7,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"gmail.com","start_offset":8,"end_offset":17,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":2}]}
```

I see that the email gets split, although I've defined the uax_url_email tokenizer for that particular analyzer.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for the help!
al